# Angular - SideMenu pasar variable al app.component

Tags: angular5

tengo una duda,he empezado en esto de angular y tengo un fichero que es un login y accede a una pagina de bienvenida que este tiene un menú al cual se puede acceder de nuevo a la pagina de bienvenida pero necesita el id del user, como paso la id al app.componet.ts?

He visto que se puede usar el events pero que esta deprecated y el observable no lo termino de entender como llevar de un lado a otro.

(La solución a esto también es una solucion para mantener una sesion hasta que se deslogue?)

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Tokens y servicios es lo que buscas.

Comment: Alguna pagina de ejemplo o video a mano tienes? @Legna

Comment: Este para el login https://codingpotions.com/angular-login-sesion

Comment: Este para los servicios: https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/servicios-angular.html